# How to disable web security when using angularjs in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, webview

I'm creating an android application in which i want to use angularjs for displaying html contents in my webview.Its not working normally.I just realized that i should disable web security option since it worked in chrome when i did that.Could anyone tell me how to do that ??

Answer (score 4):

```
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

These lines enable cross origin requests for file:// protocol but it requires API level at least 16.

Answer (score -1):

These two lines worked for me...

```
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```